# linestring output format by lat lon

Tags: postgis

Is there a way to return linestrings from my postgis database in this type of format?

Line: 1, "Road"
35.62200200, -88.98259200
35.62203500, -88.98240800
35.62202700, -88.98231000
35.62180000, -88.98163400
35.62175700, -88.98149000
35.62172500, -88.97881200
35.62172000, -88.97798500
35.62169800, -88.97752400
35.62170300, -88.97736200
35.62173900, -88.97723200
35.62180600, -88.97715200
35.62292600, -88.97608000
35.62467700, -88.97441600
35.62482100, -88.97429800
End:

Answer (score 4):

you should concat the xy's

LINESTRING('|| s."X" ||' '||s."Y" ||','|| s."X" || ' '||s."Y" || ')'',2309)

hope too be usefull for you :)

Comment: <MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>-91.427209995107873,35.698482084970728 -91.269197123447611,35.819554655906138</coordinates></LineString></MultiGeometry> is what the result is so I can concat that? I'm lost. I just need lat and long returned.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom format, or is it known? There are several [geometry output functions](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs), and you can always parse their output into something new, for example:

```
SELECT 'Line: ' || id || ', ' ||
  trim(translate(ST_AsText(ST_FlipCoordinates(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326))),
                 'MULTILINESTRINGZM()', '')) || ' End:' AS output
FROM nqatrkl;
```

Or you can dump the points and tinker around with them some other way:

```
SELECT id, time, (d).path, (d).path[1] AS part,
       ST_Y((d).geom) AS lat, ST_X((d).geom) AS lon
FROM (SELECT id, time, ST_DumpPoints(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326)) AS d
      FROM nqatrkl) AS foo
ORDER BY (d).path;
```

Comment: Dumping points would be great, I cant seem to make it work. my table is nqatrkl and I have a few fields like the_geom, id, time. Can you help me format the query correctly? I can deal with them as rows.

Comment: Its a custom format, the software takes a linestring 1.lat,lon 2.lat,lon

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
its a custom format, or is it known? There are several [geometry output functions](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs), and you can always parse their output into something new, for example:

```
SELECT 'Line: ' || id || ', ' ||
  trim(translate(ST_AsText(ST_FlipCoordinates(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326))),
                 'MULTILINESTRINGZM()', '')) || ' End:' AS output
FROM nqatrkl;
```

Or you can dump the points and tinker around with them some other way:

```
SELECT id, time, (d).path, (d).path[1] AS part,
       ST_Y((d).geom) AS lat, ST_X((d).geom) AS lon
FROM (SELECT id, time, ST_DumpPoints(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326)) AS d
      FROM nqatrkl) AS foo
ORDER BY (d).path;
```